# Spring Data o.s.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository's save method and polymorphism

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, jpa, spring-roo, spring-data-jpa

I have the following method call in my **service layer**:

```
saveAdvertisement(childminderAdvertisement);
```

..which in calls the following method from `AdvertisementServiceImpl`:

```
public void saveAdvertisement(Advertisement advertisement) {
  advertisementRepository.save(advertisement);
}
```

`AdvertisementRepository` is a `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository` parameterized as follows:

```
 JpaRepository<Advertisement, Long>;
```

Here are my entities:

`Advertisement`:

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooEquals
@RooJpaEntity(inheritanceType = "TABLE_PER_CLASS")
@Entity
public abstract class Advertisement {
...
```

`ChildminderAdvertisement`:

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooEquals
@RooJpaEntity
@Entity
public class ChildminderAdvertisement extends Advertisement {
...
```

I noticed that the `AdvertisementRepository` (which **is type-parametized with the super class Advertisement**) manages to persist instances of `ChildminderAdvertisement` properly.

My question is twofold:

**- how does Spring Data Jpa manages to persist an instance of the subclass whereas the I use the JpaRepository of the super class?**

**- What are the disadvantages (if any) of using the super class as the type parameter?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To Q1:** it is not Spring that manages to persist the instance of subclass, but it is your JPA provider. Spring only delegates the call to the JPA provider. And that in turn manages that by calling `instance.getClass()` inspecting if that `class` is an persistable class (i.e a @Entity).

**To Q2:** I personally don't see any disadvantages. OF course, if you need an extension of `JpaRepository` that works ONLY with the more specific `ChildminderAdvertisement` subtype (e.g only on save of a `ChildminderAdvertisement`  you have to log some extra stuff), then you need an implementation of the `JpaRepository<ChildminderAdvertisement, Long>`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Andrei. I see... Then it is just the matter of using a `JpaRepository<ChildminderAdvertisement, Long>` when I am only manipulating `ChilminderAdvertisement` instances and `JpaRepository<Advertisement, Long>` otherwise?

Comment: In my example above, yes. But generally it depends on your problem: on whether you need special/additional/extended operations/functionality on `ChildminderAdvertisement` (generally on a subtype). As I understand from your case in the question, your `JpaRepository<Advertisement, Long>` is just perfect to remain so and to be used also for `ChildminderAdvertisement`.